# What happens if there are too many inserts in MongoDB? How to ensure all data is stored?

Tags: mongodb

I use MongoDB to store periodically measured values. Every ~100 ms a bunch of values is inserted as document. It works fine, but I'm worried about performance issues. (I use safe inserts, it seems as if in PyMongo this is the default.)

What happens if there are more inserts per second than mongod is able to save to the hard disk? Will there be any warning or will it simply fail silently?

Is there any method to monitor write load? I've found only `db.serverStatus().writeBacksQueued` which is always set to false when I call it. How could I test how much data I have to insert to fill up the write queue?

`mongostat` displays locks. Is this something I should be worried about?

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults  locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn repl       time 
  *117     *0     *0     *0       0     2|0       0  17.4g  35.3g  3.76g      0     .:6.5%          0       0|0     0|0   124b     6k     2  SLV   09:58:10 
  *111     *0     *0     *0       0     2|0       0  17.4g  35.3g  3.76g      0     .:0.8%          0       0|0     0|0   124b     6k     2  SLV   09:58:11 
  *111     *0     *0     *0       0     2|0       0  17.4g  35.3g  3.76g      0     .:4.2%          0       0|0     0|0   124b     6k     2  SLV   09:58:1
```

Do I have to worry about write locks? What happens to an insert during a write locked time period? Is it queued and stored later on?

I am thinking about a simple replication setup using one master and one slave. Does the initial sync or a resync process lock the databases?

(I'm using version 2.4.3.)

**Update:**
I think have partly answered my own question. I managed to get up to 12.000 inserts per second using a simple while loop inserting a small test document. But qr|qw still shows that there are the read- and write queue is still empty:

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults       locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn repl       time 
 11234     *0      2     *0    1563     1|0       1  21.9g  44.3g  1.22g      0    testdb:58.9%          0       1|0     1|1   797k   980k     6  PRI   10:26:32 
 12768     *0      2     *0    1284     1|0       0  21.9g  44.3g  1.22g      0    testdb:58.0%          0       0|0     0|1   881k     1m     6  PRI   10:26:33 
 12839     *0      2     *0    1231     1|0       0  21.9g  44.3g  1.22g      0    testdb:60.3%          0       0|0     0|1   883k     1m     6  PRI   10:26:34 
 12701     *0      2     *0     910     1|0       0  21.9g  44.3g  1.22g      0    testdb:61.8%          0       0|0     0|1   858k     1m     6  PRI   10:26:35 
 12241     *0      2     *0    1206     1|0       0  21.9g  44.3g  1.22g      0    testdb:56.7%          0       0|0     0|0   843k     1m     6  PRI   10:26:36 
 11581     *0      2     *0    1406     1|0       0  21.9g  44.3g  1.22g      0    testdb:61.8%          0       0|0     0|1   811k     1m     6  PRI   10:26:37 
  8719     *0      2     *0    1210     1|0       0  21.9g  44.3g  1.22g      0    testdb:43.8%          0       0|0     0|1   618k   762k     6  PRI   10:26:38 
 11429     *0      2     *0    1469     1|0       0  21.9g  44.3g  1.22g      0    testdb:60.6%          0       0|0     0|1   804k   993k     6  PRI   10:26:39 
 12779     *0      2     *0    1092     1|0       0  21.9g  44.3g  1.22g      0    testdb:60.2%          0       1|0     0|1   872k     1m     6  PRI   10:26:40 
 12757     *0      2     *0     436     1|0       0  21.9g  44.3g  1.22g      0    testdb:59.7%          0       0|0     0|1   838k   432k     6  PRI   10:26:41
```

I suppose this means that inserts alone won't cause a lot of troubles: 
"Queues will tend to spike if you’re doing a lot of write operations alongside other write heavy ops, such as large ranged removes." (found [here](https://blog.serverdensity.com/mongodb-monitoring-mongostat/)]

**My open question:** What happens to my data if the write queue increases on long term?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have answered some of your own questions here, specifically you have a decent idea about the write lock aspect of the equation - 12,000 insert/sec gets you to ~60% write lock.  That's a reasonable level to get consistent performance - you will be getting some contention, and some ops will be a little slower, but you really want to start worrying at about 80% - like a lot of things, when you start exceeding 80% available capacity you will start hitting issues a lot more often.

In terms of other bottlenecks, and specifically how quickly you can write to disk - this can cause problems, but to look at the relevant stats over time I would recommend getting [MMS](https://mms.10gen.com/help/) installed with the [munin-node plugin](https://mms.10gen.com/help/install.html#hardware-monitoring-with-munin-node) to give you hardware and IO stats in addition to the MongoDB stats.

When you have that, the metrics you will want to keep an eye on are:

- The Average Flush time (this is how long MongoDB's periodic sync to disk is taking)
- The IOStats in the hardware tab (IOWait in particular)
- Page Faults (if your disk is busy with writes and you need to read data, they are going to be competing for a scarce resource)

It's a bit complicated then, but here's a basic idea:

- When average flush time starts to increase, be worried
- If it gets into the multiple second range, you are probably on the limit (though this depends on the volume of data written and the disk speed)
- If it approaches 60 seconds you will see performance degrade severely (the flush happens every 60 seconds, so they would essentially be queuing up)
- High IOWait is going to hinder performance too, especially if you have to read from disk at any point
- Hence looking at page fault levels will also be important

The other piece of this puzzle, which we have not mentioned yet, is the journal.  That will be persisting data to disk as well (by default every 100ms) and so it will be adding to the disk's load if it is on the same volume.  Hence if you are seeing high disk utilization, then moving the journal off to another disk would be a good idea.

There are no real "magic numbers" to stay under, in most cases it's all relative, so get a good baseline for your normal traffic, check to see if things are trending up and maybe load test to see what your limits are and when things start to degrade and you will be in good shape.

After all that pre-amble, on to some of your questions:

> What happens if there are more inserts per second than mongod is able
>   to save to the hard disk? Will there be any warning or will it simply
>   fail silently?

If you start to stress the disk to the levels described above, eventually everything is going to slow down and at some point (and this will depend on time outs, how beefy your hardware is, how you handle exceptions) your writes will fail - if you are using a recent version of pymongo then you will be using safe writes by default and those will then fail.  If you wish to be a little more paranoid, you can occasionally do a write concern of [j:true](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/#available-write-concern) which will wait to return OK until the write has made it to the journal (i.e. on disk).  This will, of course, be slower than a normal safe write, but it will be an immediate indication of disk capacity related issues, and you could use it to block/queue other operations and essentially act as a throttle to prevent your database from being overwhelmed.

> I am thinking about a simple replication setup using one master and
>   one slave. Does the initial sync or a resync process lock the
>   databases?

I think I covered locking overall at the start, but to answer this piece specifically: First, make sure you are using a [replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#deploy-a-replica-set), not master/slave.  The master/slave implementation is deprecated and not recommended for use in general.  As for the initial sync will add some load to the primary in terms of reads, but not in terms of writes, so you should be fine in terms of locking.

> What happens to my data if the write queue increases on long term?

As you can probably tell from the explanation above, the answer is very much dependent on how you write your application, how you choose to have your writes acknowledged and how much capacity you have available.  You can, essentially, be as safe as you wish when it comes to writing to disk on MongoDB, but there is a performance trade off, as mentioned with the `j:true` discussion above.

Generally, you want to figure out your limiting factor - be it locking, disk speed etc. and then track the levels over time and scale out (sharding) or up (better hardware) before you hit a hard limit and see performance problems.

One last thing, `db.serverStatus().writeBacksQueued` is actually a metric that will only ever be non-zero in a sharded environment, and it has to do with making sure that writes to a chunk during a migration are dealt with appropriately (handled by the [writeback listener](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/#what-does-writebacklisten-in-the-log-mean)).  Hence it essentially is a red herring here - nothing to do with general write volume.

Comment: https://mms.10gen.com/ is dead in 2021. Can someone recommend alternatives?

Comment: these days I think the closest thing you can get is to run your instance in Atlas, there is MongoDB compass though, it might have what you want: https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass